I can't understand what why they don't put Reaction momentum of torsional spring in FBD of whole system at B in instability analysis of column

this example is from Finite element procedures Book by Klaus-Jürgen Bathe pg 93 example 3.11
can somebody explain me why they don't consider reaction moment of torsional spring in whole system FBD but do consider in part fbd. because equilibrium equation are derived using this. i can't understand that because they skip most of the step.

You would be right, even though the effect of moment $K_r \alpha$ at hinge C and A is zero, but there is shear due to this moment that should be added to A and C
$$V_a=V_c= \frac {K_r\alpha}{2l}$$
However, if we show the shear, we should not show the moment, $K_r\alpha .$

I can't understand you what are you trying to saying. when i learn FBD , it say that if your making FBD of whole system you should include only external force of system. but they don't include external moment due to torsional spring at B. you are saying that if we show shear , we should not show moment. can you explain in generalized term or recommend some resource so that i may look into it.

We can describe it this way. The effect of torque at B has already extended U2 out and compressed U1 in, so there is no need to show it. Otherwise, we needed to have an initial displacement U1(initial) on top and subtract it by the delta.U1=2lK1/(K2r). same thing for B. Byt the forces the two spring feel ultimately are related to U final.
